# Lightning component access to scrollTop

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, html5

I would like like to get the scroll position of a tbody in a lightning component, what's the supported way to do this?

cmp.find('myComponent').getElement().scrollTop is undefined. If I do this in pure javascript it works fine, but there's something funny going on in lightning. I thought reading the dom was acceptable. Thanks for any insights into this.

```
  <table>

<tbody style="height:100px; display:block; overflow:auto;" onscroll="console.log(this.scrollTop);">
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>             
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What component has aura:id="myComponent" on it? I would expect to see something like:

```
<tbody aura:id="myComponent" ...
```

in your Lightning markup.

Also, I just checked and scrollTop is not currently exposed on SecureElement (the virtual DOM element class your code sees when running inside of Locker Service).

Please open a support case on this part of your question and let our support team know I have already created bug W-3189035 to track this.

BTW you can use element.getAttribute("scrollTop") as an alternate syntax until we get the getter/setter shorthand version exposed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the full mark up.  You're right the lightning component markup has aura:id="myComponent". I was testing outside of lightning to see if the issue was a general HTML nuance with tbody vs a lightning thing. I thought it might be something like this. This is probably a stupid question but where is the best place to find out what is and isn't supported in the lightning virtual dom, as well as what methods are available?

Comment: case # 13992694

Comment: cmp.find('myComponent').getElement().getAttribute("scrollTop") returns null, that probably makes sense if it's not a secure property that can be accessed yet?

Comment: No - something else is going on here - there is no per attribute filtering via SecureElement.getAttribute(). The DOM spec states: getAttribute() returns the value of a specified attribute on the element. If the given attribute does not exist, the value returned will either be null or "" (the empty string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window

Comment: that works for the document scroll position but I'm looking to get the scrollTop property of the tbody element with overflow auto

Comment: turning locker service off makes the scrollTop property function as expected, getAttribute("scrollTop") returns null in both cases, clearly it exists but maybe not as an attribute.